# how to load cloud endpoints apis asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, google-cloud-endpoints

```
gapi.client.load('myapi1', 'v1', function() {
        gapi.client.load('myapi2', 'v1', function() {
             gapi.client.load('myapi3', 'v1', function() {
               $rootscope.$broadcast("All loaded")
             }, '/_ah/api');
            }, '/_ah/api');
        }, '/_ah/api');
```

Right now these apis are loaded one after another. I want them to load in async and when all the apis are loaded I want to broadcast the message. Is it possible. If yes how ?

An example would be much helpful

Comment: you got yourself into a bit of a calbackhell there :-). look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var counter = 
    gapi.client.load('api1', 'v1', function() {counter--}, '/_ah/api');
    gapi.client.load('api2', 'v1', function() {counter--}, '/_ah/api');
    gapi.client.load('api3', 'v1', function() {counter--}, '/_ah/api');

    var check_if_apis_are_loaded = function(){ 
        console.log(counter)
        if(counter == 0){
            $rootscope.$broadcast("All loaded");
            clearInterval(intervalId)
        }
    }
    var intervalId = setInterval(check_if_apis_are_loaded, 300);
```

I couldnt figure out but the above answer doesnt works sometimes so I created a work around for me

Answer (score 1):

You could try smt like this:

```
 call_1 = gapi.client.load('myapi1', 'v1', function() {}, '/_ah/api');
 call_2 = gapi.client.load('myapi2', 'v1', function() {}, '/_ah/api');
 call_3 = gapi.client.load('myapi3', 'v1', function() {}, '/_ah/api');

$q.all([call_1, call_2, call_3]).then(function() {
  $rootscope.$broadcast("All loaded");
}
```

The $q service will wait for all calls to be finished and then broadcast your msg.

Hope it helps.

Also I would read up on the [$q docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and a great article on [callbackhell](http://callbackhell.com/)